# Excel Chart Data selection through VB.

Tags: excel, vba

The following code as you know chooses the data to Row 390:

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='1'!$A$2:$A$390"
```

What is the phrase to select automatically to the end of Column A as the 390 might be different in different files.
Many thanks

Comment: The question of how to get the last used cell in a given column has been asked a zillion times, e.g. here: [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```